# swift - cannot play a video loaded with AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate

Tags: swift, video, avplayer

I'm trying to play a video with AVPlayer that was loaded inside AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate but I always get a blank screen and the video never plays.

This is the code:

```
let asset = AVURLAsset(url: URL(string: "fakescheme://video.mp4")!)
asset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(ResourceLoaderDelegate(), queue: DispatchQueue.main)
let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)

let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
playerLayer!.frame = self.view.bounds;
self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer!)
player!.play()

...

class ResourceLoaderDelegate: NSObject, AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDataDelegate, URLSessionTaskDelegate {
    public func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource resourceLoadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) -> Bool {

        var newRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://example.com/video.mp4")!)
        newRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = resourceLoadingRequest.request.allHTTPHeaderFields

        let sessionTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: newRequest) { data, response, error in
            resourceLoadingRequest.contentInformationRequest?.contentType = "video/mp4"
            resourceLoadingRequest.contentInformationRequest?.isByteRangeAccessSupported = true
            resourceLoadingRequest.contentInformationRequest?.contentLength = Int64(data.count)

            resourceLoadingRequest.response = response

            resourceLoadingRequest.dataRequest?.respond(with: data)
            resourceLoadingRequest.finishLoading()
        }

        sessionTask.resume()
        return true
    }
}
```

This is the basic idea:

The fakescheme:// causes the resourceLoader() delegate to be called, inside it a new HTTP request is made to download the actual video.

And then it calls resourceLoadingRequest.dataRequest?.respond(with: data) that was supposed to cause AVPlayer to play the downloaded video.
The data variable is properly populated, but yet I always get a black screen.

The video file is also fine, it plays if I feed it directly into AVURLAsset().

I tried a million things and combinations, but can't make it play using the delegate. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I'll add some more info.

I tried doing this with an AES encrypted video where it uses 3 files - .m3u8, the encryption key and the .ts video.
I managed to make it download the .m3u8 and the key using the delegate, but again when I try to do it with the video file, I get black screen.

This leads me to thinking it may require the download to happen in portions, but I'm not sure how to properly do that.
I also can't find any documentation about it, such as - should you set the HTTP headers as if this is coming from a web server, should you set contentInformationRequest, etc. The delegate gets called 2 times:

```
// first time: 
resourceLoadingRequest.dataRequest!.requestedLength == 2,
resourceLoadingRequest.dataRequest!.requestsAllDataToEndOfResource == false

// second time: 
resourceLoadingRequest.dataRequest!.requestedLength == MAX_INT,
resourceLoadingRequest.dataRequest!.requestsAllDataToEndOfResource == true
```

I'm not sure what to make of that - I give it the entire video both times, but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work. So there are 2 problems with the above code:

1. contentType should be AVFileType.mp4.rawValue, which is "public.mpeg-4". Passing "video/mp4" or another value breaks it
2. resourceLoadingRequest.dataRequest!.requestedLength Indeed needs to be respected, so the video file needs to be sent in chunks as requested.

This is the working delegate code:

```
// this IF is an ugly way to catch the first request to the delegate
// in this request you should populate the contentInformationRequest struct with the size of the video, etc
if (resourceLoadingRequest.dataRequest!.requestedLength == 2) {
    let bytes : [UInt8] = [0x0, 0x0] // these are the first 2 bytes of the video, as requested
    let data = Data(bytes: bytes, count: bytes.count)
    
    resourceLoadingRequest.contentInformationRequest?.contentType = AVFileType.mp4.rawValue // this is public.mpeg-4, video/mp4 does not work
    resourceLoadingRequest.contentInformationRequest?.isByteRangeAccessSupported = true
    resourceLoadingRequest.contentInformationRequest?.contentLength = Int64(videoSize)
    
    resourceLoadingRequest.dataRequest!.respond(with: data)
    resourceLoadingRequest.finishLoading()
    
    return true
}

// here we are at the second request. the OS may request the entire file, or a portion of it 
// here we don't need to set any headers or contentInformationRequest, just reply with the requested data
// take a look at resourceLoadingRequest.dataRequest!.requestedLength, requestedOffset, currentOffset, requestsAllDataToEndOfResource
resourceLoadingRequest.dataRequest?.respond(with: data)
resourceLoadingRequest.finishLoading()

return true
```

This is the code of the whole file for reference:

```
import Foundation
import AVKit

class ResourceLoaderDelegate: NSObject, AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDataDelegate, URLSessionTaskDelegate {
    public func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource resourceLoadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) -> Bool {
        if ((resourceLoadingRequest.request.url?.absoluteString.contains(".mp4"))!) {
            // replace the fakeScheme and get the original video url
            var originalVideoURLComps = URLComponents(url: resourceLoadingRequest.request.url!, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)!
            originalVideoURLComps.scheme = "file"
            let originalVideoURL = originalVideoURLComps.url
            
            var videoSize = 0
            do {
                let value = try originalVideoURL!.resourceValues(forKeys: [.fileSizeKey])
                videoSize = value.fileSize!
            } catch {
                print("error getting video size")
            }
            
            if (resourceLoadingRequest.contentInformationRequest != nil) {
                // this is the first request where we should tell the OS what file is to be downloaded
                let bytes : [UInt8] = [0x0, 0x0]    // TODO: repeat .requestedLength times?
                let data = Data(bytes: bytes, count: bytes.count)
                
                resourceLoadingRequest.contentInformationRequest?.contentType = AVFileType.mp4.rawValue // this is public.mpeg-4, video/mp4 does not work
                resourceLoadingRequest.contentInformationRequest?.isByteRangeAccessSupported = true
                resourceLoadingRequest.contentInformationRequest?.contentLength = Int64(videoSize)
                
                resourceLoadingRequest.dataRequest!.respond(with: data)
                resourceLoadingRequest.finishLoading()
                
                return true
            }
            
            // this is the second request where the actual file is to be downloaded
            
            let requestedLength = resourceLoadingRequest.dataRequest!.requestedLength
            let requestedOffset = resourceLoadingRequest.dataRequest!.requestedOffset
            let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: requestedLength)
            
            let inputStream = InputStream(url: originalVideoURL!)   // TODO: keep the stream open until a new file is requested?
            inputStream!.open()
            
            if (requestedOffset > 0) {
                // move the stream pointer to the requested position
                let buffer2 = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: Int(requestedOffset))
                inputStream!.read(buffer2, maxLength: Int(requestedOffset)) // TODO: the requestedOffset may be int64, but this gets truncated to int!
                buffer2.deallocate()
            }
            inputStream!.read(buffer, maxLength: requestedLength)
            
            // decrypt the video
            if (requestedOffset == 0) { // TODO: this == 0 may not always work?
                // if you use custom encryption, you can decrypt the video here, buffer[] holds the bytes
            }
        
            let data = Data(bytes: buffer, count: requestedLength)
            
            resourceLoadingRequest.dataRequest?.respond(with: data)
            resourceLoadingRequest.finishLoading()
            
            buffer.deallocate()
            inputStream!.close()
            
            return true
        }
        
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the whole working shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource method? I would be very grateful because I am struggling with this one a lot